# What package do I need to install to have spell-checking work in Gitbook Editor?

Tags: spell-checking, electron

I installed [Gitbook Editor](https://www.gitbook.com/editor/linux). The [screenshots](https://www.gitbook.com/assets/images/editor/preview_linux.png) show that Gitbook Editor has spell-checking support on Linux.

I checked the settings to enable spell-checking but I still don't have spell-checking enabled.

This leads me to the conclusion that I am missing some kind of package(s) that provide spell-checking for Gitbook Editor.

[image: spell-checking settings]

[image: spell-checking not working]

Comment: Have you tried downloading and using older version? I think it's a bug and I saw your bug report submission. So, This answer can be closed as a bug

Comment: I went back as much as version 6.0.4 from July 2016. But spell-checking still doesn't work.

Comment: @Anwar hello, could you provide the link for the bug report ? (6.3.8 or 6.3 beta channel still not working)

Comment: @Antonello sorry I lost the link. OP was the bug reporter, so he might have the link

Comment: Hello, here it is: https://github.com/GitbookIO/feedback/issues/213